# Calculate percentage on boolean column

Tags: apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

Assuming my data has the following structure :

```
Year      | Location | New_client 

2018      | Paris    | true
2018      | Paris    | true
2018      | Paris    | false
2018      | London   | true
2018      | Madrid   | true
2018      | Madrid   | false
2017      | Paris    | true
```

I'm trying to calculate for each year and location the percentage of true value for New_client, so an example taking the records from the structure example would be

```
2018     | Paris    | 66
2018     | London   | 100
2018     | Madrid   | 50
2017     | Paris    | 100
```

Adapting from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13484279/2802552 my current script is but the difference is that instead of 1 column it's using 2 columns (Year and Location)

```
data = load...
grp = group inpt by Year; -- creates bags for each value in col1 (Year)
result = FOREACH grp {
    total = COUNT(data);
    t = FILTER data BY New_client == 'true'; --create a bag which contains only T values
    GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS Year, total AS TOTAL_ROWS_IN_INPUT_TABLE, 100*(double)COUNT(t)/(double)total AS PERCENTAGE_TRUE_IN_INPUT_TABLE;
};
```

The problem is this uses Year as reference while I need it to be Year AND District.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by both `Year` and `Location`, which will require two modifications. First, add `Location` to the group by statement. Second, change `FLATTEN(group) AS Year` to `FLATTEN(group) AS (Year, Location)` since `group` is now a tuple with two fields.

```
grp = group inpt by (Year, Location);
result = FOREACH grp {
    total = COUNT(inpt);
    t = FILTER inpt BY New_client == 'true';
    GENERATE 
        FLATTEN(group) AS (Year, Location), 
        total AS TOTAL_ROWS_IN_INPUT_TABLE, 
        100*(double)COUNT(t)/(double)total AS PERCENTAGE_TRUE_IN_INPUT_TABLE;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested this code and looks working for me:

```
A = LOAD ...
B = GROUP A BY (year, location);
C = FOREACH B  {
    TRUE_CNT = FILTER A BY (chararray)new_client == 'true';
    GENERATE group.year, group.location, (int)((float)COUNT(TRUE_CNT) / COUNT(A) * 100);
}

DUMP C;
(2017,Paris,100)
(2018,Paris,66)
(2018,London,100)
(2018,Madrid,50)
```